How to make a python program execute a function when it is closed
I want to add an auto save on close feature to my program. I asked GPT for help, and it suggested using SIGNAL or win32api to capture the close signal, but both can only work successfully when closing with Ctrl+C. I want the function to work even when the program terminal is closed.
For example, if you forget to close the program before shutting down the computer, it can also automatically perform the save function.
Here is what GPT suggest
import signal
from time import sleep
def handle_exit(signum, frame):
# do something
   with open('text.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(f"signal receive:{signum}")
        
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_exit)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_exit)
    
while 1:
    sleep(1)

I test the program, when I directly close the windows of program, it will not write to file.

Please provide your code so that people can work on it.

In Windows, when you close a terminal window, the process doesn't receive the usual signals like SIGINT (which allows graceful shutdowns).
Instead, the process is terminated abruptly by the operating system (windows). This is because the close button doesn't send any termination signals to the underlying process, so the process is immediately killed without any opportunity to handle cleanup tasks. This directly affects your code if you're relying on signal handling to save data or perform cleanup tasks.
Your code listens for SIGINT and SIGTERM to perform the save action when the user closes the program using Ctrl+C or through a kill signal.
However, if you close the terminal window or shut down the computer, the process is terminated without any signal being sent, so your handle_exit() function isn't triggered, and no data is saved in the file.
Instead you can use:
import atexit
import win32api
import win32con
from time import sleep

def save_data():
    # do aomwthing
    with open('saved_data.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write("Data saved on exit.\n")

# (close, logoff, shutdown)
def console_ctrl_handler(event):
    if event in (win32con.CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT, win32con.CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT, win32con.CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT):
        atexit._run_exitfuncs()
        return True
    return False

# Register the save function to be called on normal program exit
atexit.register(save_data)

win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(console_ctrl_handler, True)

def main():
    try:
        while True:
            sleep(1)  
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass  # Handle Ctrl+C 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The console_ctrl_handler() function now handles multiple events: CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT, CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT, and CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT. When any of these events occur, it explicitly calls atexit._run_exitfuncs() to run all registered exit handlers and  win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler and to register our custom handler for console events.
For win32 constants consider reading
win32con constants

Still no work when closing the terminal of program directly

Can you the function in which you wrapped your task or any error error message you own

I try again, if run the program with python xxx.py it can work, but if click the py file directly, it will not work

It seems the issue arises from having multiple Python versions installed on your machine. Specifically, your command line is utilizing a version  3.X that successfully executes the code, whereas your terminal in IDE uses 3.Y which likely using a different version that lacks compatibility, resulting in errors.

If you are using vscode , create a new folder named .vscode and create a file named settings.json .Now add this  line  {     "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/..../python/version/3.X" } which will force vscode to use correct python version to run code
